# Keep information when other activities are started

Tags: android, android-activity, listactivity

i have an activity that extends a ListActivity.

When the user searches on a movie the listview geting filled with movies from a ArrayList.

Is it a simple way to do so the information in the listview dont disappear when a new activity is started?

Answer (score 0):

It's the data stored in your adapter that should get saved/reloaded and the list views should be rebuild when list is reloaded and filled with the data from the adapter.

The List should always create dynamically the views in order to save resources.

As said, try saving the data from your Adapter!

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, you want to save the data that you are loading in your ListView the first time.

You need to save the data, so see the following [guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html) from the Android developers guide: